# How to convert coordinates from NAD83 to regular gps coordinates (lat/lon) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, gps, coordinates, gis

I couldn't find any library.function in python/pandas to convert coordinates from NAD83 standard to GPS lat/lon degreed.

Below is an example to reproduce the situation. I am looking for a function to convert these NAD83 coordinates to regular GPS lat/lon. All the points below are expected to be around `St. Louis, MO` (i.e. approximately `38.6270° N`, `90.1994° W`).

```
xcoords = [894557.5, 880625.2, 896551.8, 896551.8, 896497.6, 903061.1]
ycoords = [1025952, 996012.7, 1025333, 1025333, 997157.3, 1033547]
df = pd.DataFrame({'xcoords':xcoords, 'ycoords':ycoords})
```

which means

```
xcoords     ycoords 
894557.5    1025952.0
880625.2    996012.7
896551.8    1025333.0
896551.8    1025333.0
896497.6    997157.3
903061.1    1033547.0
```

datasource = http://www.slmpd.org/Crimereports.shtml

metadata   = http://www.slmpd.org/Crime/CrimeDataFrequentlyAskedQuestions.pdf (see `XCoord and YCoord - what are these coordinates of/for?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to determine the SPCS or FIPS zone for St. Louis, MO.  From the [NOAA Manual NPS NGS 5](https://geodesy.noaa.gov/library/pdfs/NOAA_Manual_NOS_NGS_0005.pdf) we get zone # 2401. Then we download the corresponding proj string from [special reference](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7906/) (alternatively you can take the necessary data from appendix A, page 68 of the NOAA Manual). With these data we can convert the SPCS data to gps lon/lat values using [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/):

```
import pandas as pd
import pyproj

xcoords = [894557.5, 880625.2, 896551.8, 896551.8, 896497.6, 903061.1]
ycoords = [1025952, 996012.7, 1025333, 1025333, 997157.3, 1033547]
df = pd.DataFrame({'xcoords':xcoords, 'ycoords':ycoords})

fips2401 = pyproj.Proj("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=35.83333333333334 +lon_0=-90.5 +k=0.9999333333333333 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs")
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")

df[['lon', 'lat']] = pd.DataFrame(pyproj.transform(fips2401, wgs84, df.xcoords.to_numpy(), df.ycoords.to_numpy())).T
```

Result:

```
    xcoords    ycoords        lon        lat
0  894557.5  1025952.0 -90.239655  38.650896
1  880625.2   996012.7 -90.288682  38.568784
2  896551.8  1025333.0 -90.232678  38.649181
3  896551.8  1025333.0 -90.232678  38.649181
4  896497.6   997157.3 -90.233154  38.571814
5  903061.1  1033547.0 -90.209794  38.671681
```

Comment: I think `lon` needs to be around +90 not -90. A minus sign difference from reality!

Comment: ha! It's really puzzling me, because I get different numbers when I run it now!! For example for the first row of (894557.5 1025952.0), I get: (-82.355684 44.781735)

Comment: negative longitude means West, positive East, and St. Louis MO is definitely west of Greenwich :)

Comment: You can verify it with Google too. For example the first row in the dataframe (second in the csv) has the address 4124 Page Blvd in the csv file. Google maps gives -90.239668 / 38.650908 for this address, which is reasonalbly close to -90.239655 / 38.650896 obtained from the conversion.

Comment: For some reason when I run the exact scripts above I get different results. For example, for the first row of (894557.5 1025952.0), I get: (-82.355684 44.781735) but you get (-90.239655  38.650896). Any thoughts?

Comment: I was wondering how can I reproduce your results. Some settings seems to be different in my machine from yours that causes the differences. I tried resetting kernel, no success... I get the same results.

Comment: I think I found why I get different results. It's because of my pyproj version. When I installed a fresh version of it on a new machine, it could reproduce your results.

Comment: another difference that I've found is that the working environment has python2 and the other one has python3 active.

Comment: I have no explanation why the results differ for an older version. To check versions run `pyproj.show_versions()`. My `PROJ` version is `6.1.1`.

Answer (score 4):

Little late but... - Below is how I was able to convert the SLMPD x,y coordinates to lat lon. First was to find out what EPSG zone we are in which was "epsg 3602 NAD83(NSRS2007) / Missouri East". This was retrieved from https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/. From general research I landed on converting it to espg:4326 "Horizontal component of 3D system. Used by the GPS satellite navigation system and for NATO military geodetic surveying."

```
from pyproj import Transformer 

#transformer to convert from (epsg 3602 NAD83(NSRS2007) / Missouri East) to 4326 (WGS84 - World Geodetic System 1984, used in GPS)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs( "epsg:3602","epsg:4326",always_xy=False)

#empty lists to hold converted x y coordinates
lat = []
lon = []

#loop through columns 'XCoord' and 'YCoord' and declare variables x and y to use in transformer. 
#note I had to change the column values from feet to meters for the transformer to correctly work
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = (row['XCoord'] / 3.28)
    y = (row['YCoord'] / 3.28)
    
    #call transformer
    x1, y1 = transformer.transform(x,y)
      
    #append to lists    
    lat.append(x1)
    lon.append(y1)
    
# add new columns to df     
df['Lat'] = lat
df['Lon'] = lon
```